# JSON.net Serialize As Different Type

Tags: json.net

I've got 2 types that share an interface... and i'm trying to **serialize**, not deserialize, an instance of InternalClass to JSON based on the schema of the ExternalClass

```
interface iShared {
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
public class InternalClass : iShared {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string ID {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

public class ExertnalClass : iShared {
    [JsonProperty("externalId")]
    public string ID {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

E.g. for an instance of InternalClass:

```
new InternalClass {ID = "abc", Name = "myName", Age = 30 }
```

rather than:

```
{"id": "abc", "name": "myName", "age": 30}
```

to serialize as

```
{"externalId": "abc", name: "myName", description: null}
```

Comment: I feel like you may be trying to use serialization for too much.  Instead, you could use [tag:automapper] to map `InternalClass` to `ExertnalClass`, then serialize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should't be possible by itself, given this object hierarchy. I see two quick ways to do this:

a) Serialize as the interface, deserialize as External Class, reserialize as External Class: This should add the extra properties with their default values.

b) If you can edit the classes, use the clean way: Create a (explicit) conversion operator or an `ToExternalClass()` method, and copy the values in there by hand (or reflection). A constructor `ExternalClass(IShared cloneThis)` might help to avoid extra work if you extend these classes in the future.